# Check remaining time with Youtube Javascript API

Tags: javascript, youtube, chromecast, youtube-javascript-api

I am embedding a Youtube video and using the YT JS API. The user is encouraged to use their Chromecast to view the embedded video. However, when the video is cast with the button in the player, `player.getCurrentTime()` and `player.getPlayerState()` become frozen, and the `onStateChange` event doesn't fire.

Is there anything I can do to work around these issues, or is this a problem only youtube can fix? Thanks!

My code:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        events:{
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event){
    console.log('Player StateChange: '+event.data); //This never runs when casting a video.
}
```

Comment: do you have any jsfiddle that I can test?

Comment: I can't replicate the issue in a Fiddle. (The YT JS API refuses to work) I did add code to my question, however.

Comment: @GiantDuck, kinda stuck in a similar situation. Did you happen to find some solution/workaround for it.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Here's the code

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


        var player;

        //execute as soon as the player API code downloads
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        // execute when the onReady event fires
        //starts video
        function onPlayerReady(event) {

            console.log("onPlayerReady");
            console.log(event);

            var duration = event.target.getDuration();

            console.log("Duration:" + duration);

            fillPlaybackRates();
        }

        //  when the onStateChange event fires
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

            console.log("onPlayerStateChange")
            console.log(event)

            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                console.log(YT);
            }
        }


        var pause = $("#pause"),
            start = $("#start"),
            mute =  $("#mute");

        pause.on('click', function () {
            player.pauseVideo();
        });

        start.on('click', function () {
            player.playVideo();
        });       


        var fillPlaybackRates = function () {

            var playbackDropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu");
            var playbackRates = player.getAvailablePlaybackRates();

            console.log(playbackRates);

            for (var i = 0; i < playbackRates.length; i++) {

                playbackDropdownMenu.append('<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">' + playbackRates[i] + '</a></li>');
            }          
        }


        var playbackRatesButton = $("#playback-rates");
        $(document).on('click','.dropdown-menu > li > a', function () {

            var option = $(this).text();
            playbackRatesButton.text(option);

            player.setPlaybackRate(option);
        });
```

Here's the full gist:  [iFrameYouTubeApi.html](https://gist.github.com/matijagrcic/9145361733e934d5ee4f)

You can also have a look here: [Continuing with Chromecast: Embedding YouTube into Custom Receivers](http://semanticmedia.byu.edu/2013/09/continuing-with-chromecast-embedding-youtube-into-custom-receivers.html)

Comment: This isn't working while casting using the button in the player.